# ORA-01017 Неправильные логин/пароль

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Через sqlplus и developer нормально подключается, но приложение, у которого в конфигах прописаны точно такие же логин пароль, выдаёт ошибку ORA-01017. Как это возможно? Могут ли быть сторонние факторы?

Comment: посмотрите тут может поможет https://qna.habr.com/q/577759

Comment: Да, поменял пароль и заработало))) Спасибо) я просто поначалу видел это но подумал это вообще не причём и пробовать не стал(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотрите [тут](http://qna.habr.com/q/577759) может поможет

идея перебить пароль заново на сервере